# verificacion de existencia de dato en oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle

esta es la sentencia que tengo

```
 $conexion = oci_connect('PROYECTO','presariocq43','localhost/XE');
        $sql="select disponibilidad from consultorio where direccion = 'Las americas'";
        $q = oci_parse ($conexion,$sql);
        oci_execute($q);
```

como se puede verificar si el `$sql` encontro un valor en esa casilla, en la base de datos la columna `disponibilidad` es de tipo numerico, la cuestion es que necesito hacer un if que vea si esta consulta trae un valor de 1 o 0

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios formas de leer los resultados, según el método que quieras aplicar. Generalmente, dado que la consulta devuelve un puntero hacia cada fila, cuando esperas más de una fila debes moverte dentro del puntero usando un bucle. Si esperas una sola fila, podrías prescindir del bucle. Aquí usaremos en todos los casos un bucle `while`, por ser la práctica habitual.

## Usando [`oci_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.oci-fetch-assoc.php)

Este método crea un array asociativo usando los nombres de columna del `SELECT`, parece que dentro del bucle hay que poner los índices en mayúscula. Al menos eso muestran los ejemplos del Manual de PHP (ver enlace)  y algunas notas de colaboradores en dicho Manual.

```
while (($row = oci_fetch_assoc($q)) != false) {
    echo $row['DISPONIBILIDAD'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

## [`oci_fetch_row`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.oci-fetch-row.php)

Es parecido al anterior, pero en vez de traer los datos en array asociativo, lo trae numérico. Nótese que los índices empiezan por `0`, por tanto la primera columna del `SELECT` se encontrará en el índice `0`.

```
while (($row = oci_fetch_assoc($q)) != false) {
    echo $row[0] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

## [`oci_fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.oci-fetch.php) con variables predefinidas con [`oci_define_by_name`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.oci-define-by-name.php)

En este caso, pre-defines la(s) variable(s) donde se recogerán los datos:

```
    oci_define_by_name($q, 'disponibilidad', $disponibilidad);
    oci_execute($q);
    while (oci_fetch($q)) {
         echo $disponibilidad . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

## [`oci_fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.oci-fetch.php) combinado con [`oci_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.oci-result.php).

```
    while (oci_fetch($q)) {
         echo oci_result($q, 'DISPONIBILIDAD') . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Al parecer hay que poner el nombre de las columnas en mayúscula siempre, por ejemplo `oci_result($q, 'DISPONIBILIDAD')` (esto no lo he podido verificar porque no tengo Oracle).

---

Hay otros métodos, pero estos son los principales.